# How to get a wired live feed from camera to phone

Tags: cameras

I need a clear video live feed from a camera to an android phone. The connection does not have to be wireless because i have to use it without any internet. The camera and phone will be 2 or 3 meters apart at most. It also has to be battery powered for at least 3 hours.

I also want the video displayed on my phone without anything else on the screen, just the live feed.

Which camera is best suitable, and what else do I need?

Comment: Any IP camera should do the job. Create a network on your smartphone and add the camera to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an IP camera like @FooBar suggested and use an app like  [IP Cam Viewer Lite - Android Apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=en&id=com.rcreations.ipcamviewer).

This app will let you communicate to the IP cam over the internet and also to IP cams in the same local network as the phone.